# How does google-api work in offline request with tokens

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

My first problem is that when I make instance of the `Google_Client` and set all the needed `scopes`, `configs`, `access types` and `others` and then generate a URL for the user to AUTH with `$client->createAuthUrl();` I allow access to my application with the google account that I'm logged. Everything works fine until I need to refresh the token.

**I explain below about the token refresh.**

```php
  $this->client = new Google_Client();
            $this->client->setAuthConfig(Storage::path('secret.json'));
            $this->client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
            $this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
            $this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
            $this->client->setRedirectUri(env('APP_URL') . '/login/google/callback');
```

So the next thing I did is to get the google user data with `laravel-socialite.` This is the data I get:

The code for the request

```php
  public function redirectToGoogleProvider()
    {
        $parameters = ['access_type' => 'offline'];

        return Socialite::driver('google')
            ->scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"])
            ->with($parameters)
            ->redirect();
    }
```

```
User {#466 ▼
  +token: "ya29.GmPhBiSuYJ_oKsvDTUXrj3lJR5jlEYV4x8d0ZuYZLnDJgYL-uePT_KuUkIb-OQUiWBElhm6ljfac5QhDTXYK3qjWjje1vsnZsTAJ7pXyjNAVd2buZy0a6xZCTdnLdFNMKMDMXa6bGbA"
  +refreshToken: null
  +expiresIn: 3599
  +id: "101509757451285102354"
  +nickname: null
  +name: "My name"
  +email: "My email"
  +avatar: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Qsbr3VmcZ50/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rdS2HIl3LCv5EYCmvyXulG8n-Ap7w/mo/photo.jpg"
  +user: array:12 [▶]
  +"avatar_original": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Qsbr3VmcZ50/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rdS2HIl3LCv5EYCmvyXulG8n-Ap7w/mo/photo.jpg"
}
```

There is no refresh token here. I assume that this is because of the way that google works in **offline mode**

> After a user grants offline access to the requested scopes, you can
>   continue to use the API client to access Google APIs on the user's
>   behalf when the user is offline. The client object will refresh the
>   access token as needed.

So I set the token that I get from the request and store in the database to the `Google_Client` instance with

`$client->setAccessToken(Auth::user()->getUserInfo()->refresh_token)`

This works. But when the token needs to be refreshed It's not getting refreshed. Instead I'm getting

> "Invalid creditianals error".

Google says that:

> "The client object will refresh the access token as needed." But this
>   is not happening.

I don't understand If I need to call a special method or how does the `Google_Client` handle the token refresh.

I've tried using the `CODE parameter` to fetch the token and refresh token with it.

`$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);`

And got this error:

```
array:2 [▼
  "error" => "invalid_request"
  "error_description" => "Could not determine client ID from request."
]
```

I'm probably not doing something right but I have no clue what.
I'm confused to be honest. Already lost a day on this without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only get a refresh token back the first time you request access of the user. After that Google assumes that you saved the refresh token.

Have the user go to their google account and revoke the access granted to this client application.

Go to the page showing Apps with access to your account:

- https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions.
- Under the Third-party apps menu, choose your app.
- Click Remove access and then click Ok to confirm

Then have them authenticate your application again. You should see the refresh toke at that time.  Make sure you save it.

### revoke

you may also be able to do

```
$client->revokeToken();
```

which should revoke the access the user granted.  However i have not tried this to see if it gets me a new refresh token.

### refresh access

This is my code for refreshing the access token NOTE its PHP i am not a larvel dev it looks very close you should be able to covert this if it doesnt work out of the box

```
/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the refresh token. So now I will store this refresh token and every time when it expires the client will get a new token by it, right? I don't need to bother to log the time that will expire to take a new token and things like that?

Comment: Unfortunately the php library doesn't work like that.   You have to feed it the refresh token and tell it to fetch a new one.   I have posted some code from one of my php projects i hope it helps you with larvel.

Comment: Remember to accept the anwser if it helped you.  It will increase your reputation as well .

Comment: on feeding refresh token, I keep getting " json key is missing the client_id field in .../vendor/google/auth/src/Credentials/UserRefreshCredentials.php:70"

surprisingly, everything was working fine last couple months. How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me share what I have come up with finally at Laravel to make it work

```
public static function getOauth2Client($o_user, $f_client) {
    try {
        $o_client = new Google_Client();
        $o_client - >setAuthConfig($f_client);
        $o_client - >setAccessType('offline');
        $o_client - >setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
        $i_token_remaining = ($o_user - >gdrive_access_ttl - (time() - $o_user - >gdrive_access_created));
        $google_client_token = ['refresh_token' = >$o_user - >gdrive_refresh_token, 'access_token' = >$o_user - >gdrive_access_token, 'created' = >$o_user - >gdrive_access_created, 'expires_in' = >$i_token_remaining, ];
        $o_client - >setAccessToken(json_encode($google_client_token));

        #token validity time is less than 60 seconds
        if ($i_token_remaining < 60 || $o_client - >isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $res = $o_client - >fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($o_client - >getRefreshToken());
            $o_user - >gdrive_access_token = $res['access_token'];
            $o_user - >gdrive_access_created = time();
            $o_user - >gdrive_access_ttl = $res['expires_in'];
        }
        return $o_client;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        print 'An error occurred: '.$e - >getMessage();
    }
}
```

To my experience:

- setAccessToken won't work with token only provided, it requires "expires_in" from me
- $o_client->isAccessTokenExpired() always returns true unless "created" is provided with $google_client_token as "created" is taken into consideration for expiration
- isAccessTokenExpired checks 30 seconds prior to expiration so my 60 seconds check can be safely removed
- $o_user is user object e.g. User::find($i_user_id);
- refresh token never changes, it is set once and forever, it is only access token that changes whenever refresh is requested
- access token ttl is 3600 - guess why?)) - so please store and update access token as well
- out of the scope of this function I also update my DB once access token changed

```
User::updateOrCreate(
    ['email' => $o_user - > email],
    [
        'gdrive_access_token' => $o_user - > gdrive_access_token,
        'gdrive_access_created' => $o_user - > gdrive_access_created,
        'gdrive_access_ttl' => $o_user - > gdrive_access_ttl,
    ]);
```

Comment: I used offline access and on the first request when the user allows the APP to use his account I got the refresh token. I use this refresh token to  get with it the access token in offline request. This way I don't need to keep track if the token is expired or anything like that. I can give a code sample if you need one.

Comment: @KristianVasilev thank you for sharing. I believe it depends of the app. My app used Google APi in offline mode, too. That's why I needed the tokens in the first place. The app was always "on" sending around 4 requests per second. Each token request is Google API hit. It affects API usage limits. Request for both refresh and access tokens counts as 2 hits. So apart from usage as such my goal was to minimize API requests number. However if this is not the case with your app then I agree the simpler the better. Either case there is no need requesting refresh token, it does not change per user